# regex to get first 3 letters and all numbers from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying my hand at regex for the first time. The input is a day of the week and a number, like `SUNDAY 2` or `WEDNESDAY 25`. I need a regex to make the output `SUN 2` or `WED 25`, i tried `^.{0,3}\d+` but it does not seem to work. Would someone mind helping me out?

Things to notice: The date can have either 1 or 2 digits

Comment: What is the programming language?

Comment: Search for: `\b([a-zA-Z]{3})[a-zA-Z]+(\s+\d{1,2})` and replace by `"$1$2"

Answer (score 3):

Working example on regexr.com:  http://regexr.com/3fcg7

First of all, you're missing the space `\s`:

`^.{0,3}\s?\d+`

But, that's still not enough, you need to acknowledge and ignore all the following letters, and then grab only the numbers.  You can do this with regex groups.  (They're zero based, with Zero being the entire match, then 1,2, etc would be the groups you create):

`(^[A-Z]{3})[A-Z]*\s?(\d)+`

That's (First group) any capital letter (at the beginning of the string) 3 times, then any capital letter 0 or more times, then a space, then (second group) any digit 1 or more times.

So for `SUNDAY 2`

Group 0:  Entire match

Group 1: SUN

Group 2: 2

Answer (score 1):

how about this one?:

`^(\w{3})\D+(\d+)`

Comment: `[^\d]` can be written as `\D`.

Comment: in my defense its really late here :) i amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
^(\w{3})\S+\s+(\d{1,2})
```

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/6dRe1G/2)

Comment: Because that's what the OP asked for.

Comment: He does have REGEX in capitals in the title of his question

Comment: We're not here to question WHY someone wants to do something, we're here to answer their very specific question about what they want to do.  If you want to comment on his question with another suggestion, go for it. If you post an answer that doesn't involve Regex, that's your right, but don't be surprised when it gets voted down.

Comment: If theres a better way, i would love to know. im pretty new to programming and regex was just my first guess. im using angularjs